# Power series solution to ODE: how do we know the series for $y$, $y'$ etc. are convergent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading an introductory example of how one can use power series to solve ODEs. It aims to find the series for $e^x$ by using the fact that $e^x$ is the unique solution to
$y' - y = 0, \quad y(0) = 1$

It starts by stating we're looking for a solution on the form $y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kx^k$. Plugging this series into the equation we get

$0 = y'(x) - y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)c_{k+1}x^k - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kx^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}((k+1)c_{k+1} - c_k)x^k$

It then states that here we are using the fact that **both of the series are absolutely convergent to sum them together**. I understand that the series for $y$ and $y'$ needs to be convergent for us to be able to sum them together but I don't understand how we know that they are convergent? It seems strange to me because I thought that usually convergence of a series will depend on the coefficients and what values of $x$ are considered. Here it seems like the example says the series are convergent for all $c_k$ and all $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assume that the power series converges and obtain  a solution . You can verify that the function you obtained is indeed a solution.  You then use a uniqueness theorem to show that this has to be the only solution. In this method the question of  proving convergence of the power series does not arise.